# Multiple str_replace Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, function, str-replace, add-filter

I can seen to get this working in my functions.php file on wordpress.

Heres my code:

```
add_filter( 'mycred_ranking_row', 'my_custom_ranking_rows', 10, 4 );
function my_custom_ranking_rows( $layout, $template, $row, $position )
{
return str_replace( '%avatar%', get_avatar( $row['ID'], 32 ), $layout );
}
add_filter( 'mycred_ranking_row', 'my_custom_ranking_rows', 10, 4 );
function my_custom_ranking_rows( $layout, $template, $user, $position )
{
$rank = mycred_get_users_rank( $user['ID'] );
return str_replace( '%level%', $rank, $layout );
}
```

as you can see i have two different add_filter functions. If i have any one of them on their own it works fine. But when i have both i get a error. Help!

Comment: they both have the same name?

Answer (score 1):

You defined the function `my_custom_ranking_rows()` twice. Try using different function names.